# Installing Plugins on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, plugins, gstreamer

Need help in installing 2 plugins

1. GStreamer ffmpeg video plugin 
   Codecs to play mpeg, divx, mpeg4, ac3, wmv and asf files
2. GStreamer plugins for mms, wavpack, quicktime,musepack
   Codecs to play

Need to manually download these plugins and install